# Kindle eBook turns into two page layout in landscape

Tags: kindle, amazon, mobi, kindle-app, kindle-fire

I created a fixed layout ebook for Kindle which displays a single page in portrait and two pages in landscape.

I didn't use any special code for this behavior so, how can I avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

Good day!
Please check `spine` in your .opf for `page-spread-*` properties.
If it is there, please remove and build your ebook again.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! I checked the .opf file for the properties you mentioned but I found nothing.

Comment: Please upload your opf file. So that i can check and answer.